# Azure Portal Data Factory Monitor & Manate Error 404 File or Directory not found

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created an Azure Data Factory pipeline and deployed it. No issues.  When I am in the Azure portal Data Factory blade, I click on the Monitor & Manage button and it takes me to a new tab in MS Edge with the following error:

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to monitor my Azure Data Factory pipeline activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the 404 error, maybe just an authentication issue. Or permissions in your Azure directory.

To monitor a pipeline or ADF in general I would suggest using PowerShell. There are loads of cmdlets to do things beyond the Azure Portal UI, including set a time slice status.

For example, to check what's currently 'In Progress' in your factory do something like this...

```
Import-Module Azure

#Params...
$AzureUser = "" # <<< enter username
$AzurePass = "" #<<< enter password

$AzureSubscription = "" # <<< enter subscription name
$ResourceGroup = "" # <<< enter resource group name


#Create credential
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $AzurePass -AsPlainText -Force
$PSCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AzureUser, $SecurePassword)

#Create Azure Connection
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $PSCredential | Out-Null

#Set context for subscription
$SubId = Get-AzureSubscription `
    -SubscriptionName $AzureSubscription | SELECT SubscriptionId 

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $SubId.SubscriptionId | Out-Null

#Get ADF details
$ADFName = Get-AzureRmDataFactory `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup | SELECT DataFactoryName

Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    | ? {$_.WindowState -eq "InProgress"}
```

Here's a link to the other cmdlets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.datafactories/v2.5.0/azurerm.datafactories

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul, I want to start getting more familiar with Azure Powershell cmdlets. 
I was able to access the portal Monitor & Manage by opening the portal in Chrome.  Seems strange that MS Azure doesn't work in MS Edge but it does work in Chrome.
Thank you for you response.
Jon